# Count lines in files in folders recursively

Tags: c#, file, recursion

In C#, what is the best way to get a count of the total number of lines in all the files in a directory and all of its subdirectories?

The obvious answer is to make a recursive function to go through all of the directories and use the strategy from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119559/c-determine-the-number-of-lines-within-a-text-file) to count the lines in each file. Is there a better/easier way?

Comment: If you can get away from writing this code yourself, you can use the `wc.exe` shell command, which should do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a LINQy way of doing so:

```
string path = @"C:\TonsOfTextFiles";
int totalLines = (from file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    let fileText = File.ReadAllLines(file)
                    select fileText.Length).Sum();
```

Comment: I like where you're going with this but your parans are mismatched.

Comment: Thanks, Dinah.  I fixed that up.  Copy/paste snafu.

Comment: Nice. It would have been nicer with lambda syntax: `Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(f => File.ReadAllLines(f).Length)`

Comment: Thanks, Lette.  To be honest, I like methods more myself (only because it seems more C#-like than SQL-like).  What's your reasons behind seeing method syntax?

Comment: Agree with you as well, Mehrdad!  I'd even go a step father with .NET 4 and parallelize it: Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).AsParallel().Sum(f => File.ReadAllLines(f).Length)

Comment: @Jesse: Parallelization is very unlikely to improve performance for such a task (it might even negatively impact it by increasing HDD seeks) as it's bound by the hard disk speed.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a better/easier way?

No, there is (in general) no better way to get the number of lines in a file than by counting them.

In order to find the total number of lines in all files, you will have to get the total number of lines in each file at some point. There's really no way around that.

Comment: Why the downvote? If there's a reason you think this didn't deserve the upvote, it would be polite to point that out instead of just doing a hit-and-run. Otherwise, the only thing I can think of is you didn't want this above your answer for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a better way. Walking through a directory structure to all subdirectories inherently lends itself to being done recursively. As for counting the lines in the file, you really have no choice but to open the file up and count the lines. Note that you do need to be aware of blowing up your stack so you might have to manually simulate recursion using a `Queue`.

Since it's relatively easy to get that method coded up correctly, clearly and concisely I think that is what you should do and move on to adding value elsewhere.

Comment: -1 Thats not an answer to the question, just a rather back handed insult.

Comment: @Nick: It is absolutely not a backhanded insult and it's unfortunate that you take it that way.

Comment: @Evan Carroll: That's fine, again, I don't see the insult at all and I wish someone would be more explicit about how I am being insulting so that can edit accordingly and avoid such unintentional insults in the future.

Comment: I don't see anything insulting in that answer... +1 for mentioning the risk of stack overflow

Comment: Actually, this is a great reminder.  So, using Queue is a better choice ? @jason

Answer (score 1):

The strategy you described works well. An alternative approach instead of a recursive function (basically DFS) is to use BFS. Something like:

```
int CountLines(string path)
{
    var queue = new Queue<string>();
    queue.Enqueue(path);
    int count = 0;
    while (queue.Count > 0) {
        string dir = queue.Dequeue();
        foreach (var subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
            queue.Enqueue(subdir);
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
            count += GetLineCount(file); 
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: this solution is great!  I just wonder: comparing to the recursive fuction, whose performance is better?

Answer (score 0):

I think that post sufficiently explains the latter part of your question. As far as the directory traversing, check out this http://dotnetperls.com/recursively-find-files

UPDATE: there is an abstraction over this: I was really hoping you would read the link, but here it is http://dotnetperls.com/recursive-file-list-1

Comment: Actually, his question is not how to do it recursively but rather if there is a better alternative.

Comment: there is, that page talks about all of the methods to do this., i linked to the framework way.

Answer (score 0):

For finding the files, why not just use something like:

```
Directory.GetFiles("C:/some/path", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

This will give you the results of a recursive search.

Comment: If the user does not have permission to enumerate some of the sub directories contained within, this causes an exception. In a general case, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Please God, forgive me:

```
@echo off
set sum=0
for /r %%f in (*.cs) do find /v /c "$$some nonsense string$$" %%f >> test.dat
for /f "tokens=3 delims=:" %%i in (test.dat) do set /a sum += %%i
echo total lines = %sum%
del test.dat
```

Isn't C#, but it's fun.

**EDIT:** This can be more memory efficient, as it doesn't use `ReadAllLines`, but one at once:

```
string basePath = @"C:\some\path";
Console.WriteLine(
    Directory.GetFiles(basePath, "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Sum(file => 
        {
            int lines = 0;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
                while(reader.ReadLine() != null) lines++;
            return lines;
        }));
```