# Counting how many lines in a file, excluding certain lines

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have a file that contains many lines, I am using a streamreader to read the file. What I need to do is count how many lines there are in this file, but at certain points the file contains a line of text as such: "-----". SO what I need to do is count the number of lines in the file excluding the lines that contains "-----".

I do not want to use the streamreader like this:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader();
var x = reader.ReadLine()
```

and check if x contains "-----" and if it does increment a counter, as this is very intensive as the file would be a huge file.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this question can be found at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119559/determine-the-number-of-lines-within-a-text-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
var count = File.ReadLines("foo.txt")
                .Count(line => !line.Contains("-----"));
```

Note that [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) reads in a streaming fashion, so this will only actually read one at a time.

However, that *effectively* will do what you've described yourself *not* wanting to do... just in a rather prettier way. You say it's "very intensive" - but this in *inherent* work. If you're trying to count the number of lines containing a certain pattern, you've clearly *got* to read each line. I don't see how you think that's avoidable.

Comment: Thanks for this...works well but is it not possible to do it without reading every line?

Comment: @johnnie: How could that even slightly be possible? Every line can potentially increment the count or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
File.ReadLines("path").Count (l => !l.Contains("-----"));
```

ReadLines returns IEnumerable. Due to Linq's lazy evaluation the whole file won't be read into memory in order to count the number of lines.

Using

```
File.ReadAllLines(...)
```

which is what I mistakenly used in my answer originally *would* read the whole file into memory.

Comment: That reads the lines that contain ----. But it should be the other way around.