# Is there a better way to count the lines in a text file?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, text-files, streamreader

Below is what I've been using. While it does work, my program locks up when trying to count a rather large file, say 10,000 or more lines. Smaller files run in no time.

Is there a better or should I say faster way to count the lines in a text file?

Here's what I'm currently using:

```
    Dim selectedItems = (From i In ListBox1.SelectedItems).ToArray()
    For Each selectedItem In selectedItems
        ListBox2.Items.Add(selectedItem)
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(selectedItem)

        Dim FileQty = selectedItem.ToString
        'reads the data file and returns the qty
        Dim intLines As Integer = 0
        'Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(TextBox1_Path.Text + "\" + FileQty)
        Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
            TextBox1.Text += sr.ReadLine() & ControlChars.CrLf
            intLines += 1
        Loop
        ListBox6.Items.Add(intLines)
    Next
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
Imports System.IO.File 'At the beginning of the file

Dim lineCount = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").Length
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119559/determine-the-number-of-lines-within-a-text-file) question.

Comment: Very nice...I had to tweak it a bit for VB but it seems like day and night from before!

Comment: Lol, tweak.  The answer was already in VB, but he just accidentally added the Semicolon.  Sorry, I lawl'd and had to point that out.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you make your iteration as efficient as can be, if you hand it a large enough file you're going to make the application freeze while it performs the work.

If you want to avoid the locking, you could spawn a new thread and perform the work asynchronously.  If you're using .NET 4.0 you can use the [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class to make this very easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBox2.Text = File.ReadAllLines(scannerfilePath).Length.ToString()
```