# no System.IO.File.ReadLines(file).Count() in .Net 4?

Tags: c#

I am trying to read the number of lines of a file
I found here (stackoverflow) that the best way to read the number of lines in a large file is by using the following code:

```
int count = System.IO.File.ReadLines(file).Count();
```

However, I can't make it compile. Does any know what is the problem?

> Error 5   `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'` does not
>   contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'` could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thanks,
Eyal

Comment: Do you have the line `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file?

Comment: you have to use a `foreach` AFAIK.

Comment: @dlev - that was the problem. I added the using 'system.linq' and now its OK. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Count<T>()` is an extension method for objects of `IEnumerable<T>`. Try adding a `using` statement for the namespace `System.Linq`.

Answer (score 3):

Could you do:

```
int count = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\filepath\file.txt").Length;
```

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, this could (will) perform badly for large files. For a similar question with more detailed explanation why, view [Determine the number of lines within a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119559/determine-the-number-of-lines-within-a-text-file)

Comment: "read the number of lines in a **large file**" If you did `ReadAllLines` it will need to temporarly store the entire file in ram. `ReadLines` only needs to store the current line.

Comment: Good point. For a large file this would be very inefficient. I have updated my answer to link to a similar question.

Answer (score -1):

This is count for line from window application in read from text file:

```
int linecount = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\yfile.txt").Length;
MessageBox.Show(linecount != null && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(linecount.ToString())) ? linecount.ToString() : "Unable To Count");
```

Comment: this is count for line from window application in read from text file