# How to count the text file which split with newline character

Tags: c#, file-io, count, split

I have a file text which splited by newline character. the text file such this:

```
merah.dc
kuning.dc
hijau.dc
biru.dc
orange.dc
mahopermanent.dc
```

I want to count them by splitting with a newline character. so, the count of them are 6. I could only do this with looping:

```
int count = 0;
string path = "directory\\admin.txt";
StreamReader moco = File.OpenText(path);
string s; 
while ((s = moco.ReadLine())!= null)
{
    count++;
}
```

I want to count them with a simple way like the PHP syntax:

```
<?php
$file = file("directory\\admin.txt");
$count = count($file);
echo $count;
?>
```

The above syntax able to counts them without looping. Just use `file()` and `count()`. is any function in C# which equals with that function ?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/119572/2974754) answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine the number of lines within a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119559/determine-the-number-of-lines-within-a-text-file)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) without loading whole file into the memory (of course this method can be useful if your file is large)

```
int count = File.ReadLines(filename).Count();
```

Comment: +1 I continue to forget that method. Started using ReadAllLines and still not getting into the IEnumerable tricks. However should be mentioned that this is available from NET 4.0 onward

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** You can use `ReadAllLines()` function to get all `Lines` from the given file path as a `String Array`.

**Step 2:** you can invoke `Length` property on the obtained `String Array` to get the `Count` of Total Lines

Try This:

```
using System.IO;

String [] allLines=File.ReadAllLines(@"directory\admin.txt");
int length=allLines.Length;
```

Comment: what different with `allLines.Count()` ? whether `Count()` is method and `Length` is properties ?

Comment: @Sudhakar - `Count()` is an extension method over `IEnumerable<T>`. `Count` property you talking about is a property exposed by `ICollection<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = File.ReadAllLines(@"directory\\admin.txt").Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to split them by a new character, use File.ReadAllLines (which returns an array of strins, each element is a line).

```
int lineCount = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt").Length;
```

If you want to use split, then:

```
int lineCount = File.ReadAllText("test.txt").Split('\n').Count();
```

ReadAllText returns a strin with the entire content of the file.

Comment: ReadAllLines it about 200/300 ticks faster than the latter (time measured with a stopwatch).

Comment: @RodrigoSilva - Any reference for your statement - `ReadAllLines it about 200/300 ticks faster than the latter`?

Comment: You're right, it was an "unfounded" statement. I'll correct it: my measurements concluded it took a bit less time. I can't explain the theoretical reason behind it nor do I claim my results are 100% accurate, they're just rough tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can `Split()` the textfile

```
StreamReader moco = File.OpenText(path);
string s;
string splitArray[] = s.Split('\n'); //Split on newline

int length = splitArray[].Length;
```