# Less memory intensive way to count lines in text file in vb

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have files that may contain up to 40,000,000 lines of data (records) in text files.

I need a memory efficient way to count how many lines are in a file.

I have tried:

```
Dim this As Integer
this = File.ReadAllLines(txtInPath.Text).Length
MsgBox(this)
```

where txtInPath is a text box in my form.

This code causes out of memory exception.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/119559), particularly the "belated" addition.

Comment: That's exactly what worked! Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine the number of lines within a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119559/determine-the-number-of-lines-within-a-text-file)