# the process cannot access the file because it's used by another process

Tags: c#, csv, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm facing a problem with my code in C# where I'm writing to csv file (saving input data from textboxes).On the same time I want to add row number to each new row saved. I wrote this code but the error is showing: Sysytem.IO.IOException 'The process cannot acess the file because it's used by another process'.
I made sure I'm closing the streamwriter and streamreader. I don't know how else I can improve my code.

```
var filePath = "csvFile.csv";

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)))
try
{
    //Count rows in csv file and add new row number
    string file = new StreamReader("csvFile.csv").ReadToEnd();
    string[] lines = file.Split('\n');
    int countOfLines = lines.GetLength(0);

    sw.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}"
        , countOfLines + 1
        , txtEventName.Text
        , txtEventType.Text
        , txtAttributeName.Text
        , txtAValue.Text
        , txtEventDescrip.Text);

    // Ensure data is written to disk  
    sw.Close();
}
catch()
{
}
```

Comment: It would help if you provided a complete sample of your code and indent it properly.

Comment: There will never be more than one line in the CSV file, because you always create a new one by `FileMode.Create`. What you probably want to do is to open the file with `FileMode.Append`, *after* you have read its content by a StreamReader to get the number of already existing lines. However, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/119572/1136211) for a more efficient way to get the current line count.

Answer (score 0):

You received this error ('The process cannot access the file because it's used by another process') because you are trying access file again by using `StreamReader` while it's already opened by `StreamWriter`.

To resolve your problem you should first count a number of lines in your file and after that, you should append new text to file.

```
 var countOfLines = File.ReadLines("csvFile.csv").Count();

 using (StreamWriter sw = 
            new StreamWriter(new FileStream(filePath,
                              FileMode.Create | FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)))
          try
          {             
                sw.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}",
                    countOfLines + 1,
                    txtEventName.Text
                  , txtEventType.Text
                  , txtAttributeName.Text
                  , txtAValue.Text
                  , txtEventDescrip.Text);
...
```

You should make attention to `FileMode` parameter of `FileStream`. You should use `FileMode.Create | FileMode.Append`, if you left in your code `FileMode.Create` you will have always one line of data in your file ([msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

Comment: Thank You all,I solved my problem by placing code that counts csv file rows outside the StreamWriter code: //Count rows in csv file and add new row number
            var lineCount = 0;
            using (var reader = File.OpenText(@"csvFile.csv"))
            {
                while (reader.ReadLine() != null)
                {
                    lineCount++;
                }
            }

Answer (score 0):

You should access your `StreamReader` instance outside of the `using` statement for `StreamWriter`. It should be inside of its own `using` statement. You are effectively trying to read from a file that is currently also being written to.